# How can I run Ubuntu with minimal system resources?

Tags: performance

I installed Ubuntu on a quite old PC (Pentium 4 2GHz on-board graphics). How can I turn off all unneeded effects to speed up the system-experience?

I know a better solution would have been to just install Xubuntu or Lubuntu, but I would like to know how to run the standard Ubuntu on a low-resources computer.

Comment: maybe use xubuntu instead?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please outline the exact specs of the "quite old pc"?  It is hard to answer without knowing; it could quite well turn out there is not much you can do.

Be advised, if you are skirting the fringes of the basic requirements it may be difficult to use Ubuntu.

Some things to try would turning off as many desktop effects as possible.  Do not open many programs at once.

Is there a reason you need to use the Ubuntu Unity desktop?  You can install Ubuntu using the server edition and then insall your own desktop after that.  See http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/minimal for more on installing on lower resource pc's.

Comment: OK, I added the PC specs to the question. How can I turn off all desktop effects?

Comment: Key to this also, is how much RAM the PC has.  With shared graphics as well that will reduce that RAM number as well as some is used for the graphics.